# Problemas en visualizar el video streaming en la GUI: label no definido

Tags: python

Quiero que mi cámara se ejecute en una de mis ventanas secundarias, pero me genera un error con el *lblVideo*. No entiendo por qué. Me dice que no está definido pero sí lo definí. Tengo dudas con *restempor* a si iría en `self`.
También imagino que por ser segunda ventana me da eso pero no logro ver qué es.

```py
class VentanaSecundaria1(tk.Toplevel):   # la ventana secundaria para los medicos se crea apartir de la clase tk.Toplevel para crear una ventana en la parte superior de todas las otras ventanas. 
    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):    # args y kwargs  permiten pasar un número variable de argumentos a una función, sirve cuando el número de parámetros de entrada puede ser variable
        super().__init__(*args, **kwargs) # utilizo super para conserva los metodos de clase 
        self.geometry("2000x800")    
        self.config(background='#42606B')   #configuracion 
        self.title("MENU")                   #titulo 
        self.fondo1=PhotoImage(file="menu.gif")      #imagen de fondo
        tk.Label(self, image=self.fondo1).  place(x=-1, y=0)  #configuracion de imagen 
        cap= None

        self.boton_modificar = tk.Button(self, text='Modificar', command=self.abrir_ventana_modificar) 
        self.boton_modificar.config(background='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=13, font=("Times New Roman", 50))
        self.boton_modificar.place(x=1400, y=225, width=450,  height=170)
        
        self.boton_registro_llegada= tk.Button(self, text='Llegada')#command=self.abrir_Ventana_registro)
        self.boton_registro_llegada.config(background='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=13, font=("Times New Roman", 50))
        self.boton_registro_llegada.place(x=1400, y=425, width=450,  height=170)

        self.boton_registro_salida= tk.Button(self, text='Salida') # command=self.abrir_Ventana_mapa)
        self.boton_registro_salida.config(background='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=13, font=("Times New Roman", 50))
        self.boton_registro_salida.place(x=1400, y=625,  width=450,  height=170)


        self.boton_salir= tk.Button(self, text='Regresar')  
        self.boton_salir.config(background='#011B61', fg='#FFFFFF', bd=7, font=("Times New Roman", 40), command=self.destroy)
        self.boton_salir.place(x=80,  y=850, width=290,  height=120) 

        self.iniciar=tk.Button(self,text="Iniciar",font=("Times New Roman",  40), bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=5, relief="groove", command=self.visualizar)
        self.iniciar.place(x=700,y=850, width=290,  height=120)

        self.Finalizar=tk.Button(self,text="Finalizar",font=("Times New Roman",  40), bg='#FFFFFF', fg='#0230AD', bd=5, relief="groove", command=self.finalizar)
        self.Finalizar.place(x=1000,y=850, width=290,  height=120)
        
        lblVideo1 = Label(self) 
        lblVideo1.grid(column=0, row=1, columnspan=2)

    def abrir_ventana_modificar(self):
        self.ventanamodificar_M = ventanamodificar()

    #def iniciar(self):
        #  global cap
        # cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        # self.visualizar()

    def visualizar(self):
        global cap
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)
        if cap is not None:
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            if ret == True:
                frame = imutils.resize(frame, width=640)
                frame = cv2.cvtColor(frame, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
                im = Image.fromarray(frame)
                img = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=im)
                lblVideo1.configure(image=img)
                lblVideo1.image = img
                lblVideo1.after(10, visualizar)
            else:
                lblVideo.image = ""
                cap.release()

    def finalizar(self):
        global cap
        cap.release()
```

Me produce este error:

> NameError: name 'lblVideo1' is not defined

Comment: Defines `lblVideo1` en el método `__init__`, pero esa variable no es accesible fuera del método, **es una variable local**. Si la vas a usar en otros métodos de la clase (como `visualizar`) definela como un atributo de instancia `self.lblVideo1 = Label(self)` y accede a ella a través de una referencia a la instancia (`self` para los otros métodos de instancia), por ejemplo `self.lblVideo1.configure(image=img)`.  Te recomiendo hacer lo mismo con `cap`, las variables globales suelen ser una mala idea excepto para casos muy concretos, mejor usa un atributo de instancia ya que estas usando clases.